# SQL: Select all observations within a series of date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, olap, dimensions, fact-table

I have an OLAP structured sql server database. My fact table is sales.

I have 2 dimensions and 1 fact table. The dimensions are as follows:

```
Product (ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, ListPrice)
Promotion (ProductID, Discount, StartDate, EndDate)
```

And the Fact table:

```
Sales (SalesID, CustomerID, ProductID, Date, ProductReturned)
```

Note, the Promotion dimension does not have a unique identifier of its own. I believe that the four element tuple is ~composite primary key.

First, I'd like to create a primary key called `PromotionID`, storing it in this dimension. Next, I'd like to iterate through each of the observations in the sales fact table, if the date of an observation falls within the range `StartDate` -> `EndDate` in the Promotion dimension, I want to assign a foreign key attribute as the `PromotionID`. Lastly, I want to select all observations from the sales fact table where the FK `PromotionID` is not `NULL`.

Two questions:

1. How do I accomplish this affect?
2. Are the above steps the easiest way to reach this goal - or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, SQl-Server. Tagged above as of now :)

Comment: Please add your table DDL, sample data, desired results, and your best try at the queries.